# Segregate a list of dictionary into multiple lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which contains below data

```
[{
  "col1":"1",
  "col2":"a"
},{
  "col1":"2",
  "col2":"b"
},{
  "col1":"3",
  "col2":"c"
}]
```

Here my dictionary key fields are dynamic ( e.g. col1, col2).

I want to segregate this dictionary data into multiple list based on key field grouping.
Result which i'm trying to achieve should look like this

```
{
  "col1":["1","2","3"],
  "col2":["a","b","c"]
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it in few lines rather then writing multiple for loops?

Comment: Consider to use `defaultdict` from collections module to get all same `keys` and group their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution?  You could try this `collections.defaultdict()` to group all items with the same `key`:
To make it readable it's perfect fine to use `loops`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

lst = [{
  "col1":"1", "col2":"a"
},{
  "col1":"2", "col2":"b"
},{
  "col1":"3", "col2":"c"
}]

for d in lst:
    #print(d)  # d is a dict
    for k, v in d.items():
        dd[k].append(v)
        
print(dd)
```

Results:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'col1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```